# Transposing keys with lowest values of a map to a set

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, set

I have a map of word frequencies `Map<String, Integer>`.  I need to make a set of the least occurring words.  Say the lowest occurring words all appeared twice, I need to make a set of all these twice-occurring words.  So far I have:

```
public Set findRarest()
{
    int occurrence = 1000;  //high initial value for word length
    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> item : wcMap.entrySet())
    {
        if (item.getValue() > occurrence);        //most likely for performance
        else if (item.getValue() == occurrence)
        {
            rarest.add(item.getKey());
        }
        else                                      //found new lowest count
        {
            rarest.clear();
            rarest.add(item.getKey());
        }
    }
    return rarest;
}
```

This seems a little convoluted to me.  Are there native collection tools to get this done?

Comment: Not really.  Guava's `Multiset` might make it a little less awkward, but this is basically the way to do it -- except that there's no reason whatsoever to have the `if (item.getValue() > occurrence);` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your code even works as written. Two things:

1. Initialize `occurrence` with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead of just some arbitrary large value.
2. Update the value of `occurrence` whenever you find a word which occurs less often.

Other than that, your solution is fine. I'm not sure you could get anything much cleaner restricting yourself to [Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) classes.

Updated code:

```
public Set findRarest()
{
    Set<String> rarest = new HashSet<String>();

    int occurrence = Integer.MAX_VALUE;  //high initial value for word length
    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> item : wcMap.entrySet())
    {
        if (item.getValue() == occurrence)
        {
            rarest.add(item.getKey());
        }
        else if ( item.getValue() < occurrence )
        {
            occurrence = item.getValue();
            rarest.clear();
            rarest.add(item.getKey());
        }
    }
    return rarest;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did miss the update of the occurrence.  The Integer.MAX_VALUE is also a good idea.  I have used the first "if" to improve performance as once you encounter a short word you'd only do one evaluation most of the time.  Your solution does two evaluations most of the time.  I may be missing something.

Comment: As @LouisWasserman stated in his comment, in most cases you're wasting your time optimizing at that level. The *javac compiler* and the [jit compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) are really good at making those kinds of optimizations. I'm guessing if you actually did some timing tests you'd find it won't make a difference.